# sorting objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

> Sort the below dictionary/ array key using Javascript and output the information in key:value format on a Polymer interface. The entire numeric key should be sorted in an ascending order and all the alpha keys should be sorted in ascii, ascending order.
>
> ```
> Dictionary = {'34': 'thirty-four', '90': 'ninety',
> '91': 'ninety-one'' 21': 'twenty-one',
> '61': 'sixty-one', '9': 'nine',
> '2': 'two', '6': 'six', '3': 'three ',
> '8': 'eight', '80': 'eighty', '81': 'eighty-one',
> 'Ninety-Nine':  '99', 'nine-hundred':  '900',}
> ```

Comment: We don't do your homework.

Comment: so far i have managed to do this but it still doesn't sort please help

Comment: You have managed to do what? If you you want help with your code, then show your code.

Comment: var myObj = {
     34:'thirty-four',
     90:'ninety',
     91: 'ninety-one',
     61: 'sixty-one',
     2: 'two',
     9: 'nine',
     21: 'twenty-one',
     3: 'three',
     6: 'six',
     8: 'eight',
     80: 'eighty',
     81: 'eighty-one',
     'Ninety-nine' :99,
     'nine-hundred' :900,

  },
keys = [],
  k, i, len;

for (k in myObj) {
  if (myObj.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
    keys.push(k);
  }
}
keys.sort();
len = keys.length;
for (i = 0; i <= len; i++) {
  k = keys[i];
  alert(k + ':' + myObj[k]);
}

Comment: not homework....its an error i ran into and the sorting wont work

Comment: Curious - it's a valid question, and someone voted a working answer down - odd :) @PrinceBobKimani try the answer below? Not sure what you need on the text sorting though - clarification?

Answer (score -1):

```
/**
 this code has a trailing comma that should be removed
 and it has a double quote and missing comma
 **/
    var Dictionary = {'34': 'thirty-four', '90': 'ninety', '91': 'ninety-one'' 21': 'twenty-one', '61': 'sixty-one', '9': 'nine', '2': 'two', '6': 'six', '3': 'three ', '8': 'eight', '80': 'eighty', '81': 'eighty-one', 'Ninety-Nine': '99', 'nine-hundred': '900',}
    var Dictionary = {
'34': 'thirty-four',
'90': 'ninety',
'91': 'ninety-one',
'21': 'twenty-one',
'61': 'sixty-one',
'9': 'nine',
'2': 'two',
'6': 'six',
'3': 'three ',
'8': 'eight',
'80': 'eighty',
'81': 'eighty-one',
'Ninety-Nine': '99',
'nine-hundred':'900'
};
```

[Sort JavaScript object by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467129/sort-javascript-object-by-key#5467142)

```
var newDictionary = {}, keys = Object.keys(Dictionary), i=-1, len = keys.length;
keys.sort();
while (++i < len) {
  newDictionary[keys[i]] = Dictionary[keys[i]];
}
console.log(newDictionary);

// something along this line?

//This gives the following out put:
Object { 2: "two", 3: "three ", 6: "six", 8: "eight", 9: "nine", 21: "twenty-one", 34: "thirty-four", 61: "sixty-one", 80: "eighty", 81: "eighty-one", 90 : "ninety", 91 : "ninety-one", "Ninety-Nine" : "99", "nine-hundred" : "900" }
```

Comment: @PrinceBobKimani If this helped, please click the up arrow and select as the accepted solution?